# APNS not working on AdHoc Distribution Profile on Google App Engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, ssl, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

After push notifications were successfully sent and received using general iOS Development and APNs Development iOS certificates, I created iOS Distribution and APNs Production certificates for AdHoc testing.

At first, i created an iOS Distribution certificate and installed it to the Keychain. Then I created APNs Production certificate, installed it to the Keychain, and uploaded .p12 file to the server. Finally, I created provisioning profile and signed it with an iOS Distribution certificate. But when I created and ipa-file and installed it on device, push notifications are not received.

Device asked for permissions and i got a unique device ID, server side is fine. 
Had anyone faced that problem and what guide/tutorial followed?

I followed this article

http://gnuromancer.org/2013/04/21/google-app-engine-apns/

Comment: You're stating a problem, not asking a question. Please specify a not-too-broad problem you're facing.

Comment: Did device ask your permissions for displaying notifications? Did you get device unique id? Is all fine at server side?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Google App Engine server.

```
 ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
.withCert(inputStream, "password").withSandboxDestination()
.withNoErrorDetection().build();
```

If you are about to create AdHoc or AppStore build, along with different certificate and provisioning profile,  the `withSandboxDestination()`  line has to be changed to `withProductionDestination()`.